# Launch Native iPhone Maps Application in HTML 5 or Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, google-maps, web-applications

I am developing an iPhone app that I would like to include turn by turn driving directions and the iPhone Maps Application user interface.

I am developing the app as a web app using HTML 5, CSS, and JavaScript.  Is there a way to bridge the Native iPhone maps app to be called when you have a link to a google maps url?  I would love to have a link that says directions to a location and then when clicked it launches the iPhone Maps app and imports the address into the app.

The framework that I am using to develop the app is JqueryMobile.  Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2):

`http://maps.google.com/` URLs automatically open in the Maps app.

Comment: use maps.apple.com instead. This url will open maps app. On computers, it will redirect to standard Gmap site.